# What is this Ceramic Container?

Tags: equipment

What is [this](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=215863151922901&set=a.195493357293214.1073741828.100004976521088&type=1&theater) Ceramic Container?

I found this at a goodwill and have no clue what it is ??

[image]

Comment: Can you add a picture of the inside, or bottom of the "lid."  I suspect you may have a butter bell of unusual design, but it is hard to tell.

Comment: are there two lids? Does the one shown on the container sit inside  the jar, like for stamping the contents down?

Comment: need more pictures like what's underneath that chimney thing. Can you take a picture with a quarter next to it for size? Initial guess is it could be a butter crock but it wouldn't need that lid. Dish to make terrines? the lid used for presentation?

Answer (score 2):

Its a butter bell / butter keeper.  My parents have one.  You put water in the bottom, butter in the bell under the top/lid and that forms an airtight seal allowing you to keep the butter at room temperature.

Here's one for sale showing both parts clearly.

http://www.kitchenandcompany.com/Storage-And-Cleaning/Countertop-Organization/Butter-Dishes/_/Norpro-4-Butter-Keeper?tc=gfs13&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=Norpro%204%22%20Butter%20Bell%20Butter%20Keeper&gclid=CM2C1ZSRmroCFSpk7Aodt3kAgw

Comment: The link is dead due to bitrot.  Can you find something better?  Perhaps posting an image would be more durable ?

Answer (score 1):

It's a [French butter dish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_butter_dish), used for keeping butter fresh without refrigerating it.

Comment: This is what others suggested in the comments. But we cannot really tell without seeing what's underneath. And besides, what is the second (flat) lid good for in a butter dish?